# Any API for creating a ForeignSecurityPrincipal in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Is there an API for creating/adding foreign security principals to Active Directory? I know if you invoke the Add method on a group and pass in a user's SID in the format " " then AD will automatically create the FSP for you, but I want to create an FSP that won't be added to a group (it will be used in the ManagedBy attribute).

I can't see why there should be any kind of restriction on creating our own FSPs if we can do it already by adding a user to a group, surely there can be an API that lets you just specify the SID and it will create the FSP for you just like when you specify a SID for a group member that comes from another domain.

At the moment my workaround is to just create a temporary group, add the user from the external domain to the group so that the FSP gets created for them, and then delete the group... but that is pretty messy and some customers will not be happy with that happening every time they use our program (understandably).

Comment: Please ask yourself why you would need FSPs that Windows does not deem necessary. I would like to point out that there exists a powershell command to check all FSPs as to whether they are still required and purge them otherwise. I guess that all FSPs you added manually will be removed by this command...

Comment: @Alexander I already said it will be used in the ManagedBy attribute. Basically I want to set a user/group from an external domain as the Manager of a group in another domain. If you try to do this by setting ManagedBy to the distinguished name of the external user it fails (because AD does not create an FSP for it), if the user already has an FSP and you set ManagedBy to that FSP then it works.

Comment: @Alexander oh and what is this Powershell command that clears out FSPs? I can't find any references to such a command online anywhere